# Fluent NHibernate many-to-many create clustered index on link table

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have two entities in a many-to-many relationship.

```
 public class SecurityGroupMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<SecurityGroup>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<SecurityGroup> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Actions).ParentKeyColumn("securityGroupId").ChildKeyColumn("actionId").
            LazyLoad().Table("ActionGroups");

        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Members).ParentKeyColumn("securityGroupId").ChildKeyColumn("userId").
            LazyLoad().Inverse().Table("UserGroups");

        mapping.Map(x => x.Name).Length(64);

    }
}
```

So I want to create an clustered index on both columns (userId, securityGroupId) from table UserGroups.

Or just to create a Primary Key on UserGroups on them both columns, as at same time could not be two same links.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're wanting NHibernate's `SchemaExport` tool to generate these indexes/keys for you.

For many-to-many ***bags*** (FluentNHibernate's default collection type), SchemaExport generates:

```
create UserGroups (
    securityGroupId INT not null,
    userId INT not null,
)
```

For many-to-many ***sets***, it generates:

```
create UserGroups (
    securityGroupId INT not null,
    userId INT not null,
    primary key (securityGroupId, userId)
)
```

... so just add `.AsSet()` to your mapping.

```
mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Members)
    .AsSet()
    // ... etc.
```

It makes sense, really, if you think about what bags and sets are.  The elements of a set are supposed to be unique, whereas bags don't have a uniqueness requirement.

Comment: Up Voted for visibility, I was searching on how to do this for "By Code" and the same solution works for "By Code" also

Answer (score 0):

You need `IAutoMappingOverride<Member>` instead at the top of your code. And you only need one `mapping.HasManyToMany`. If you want a bidirectional relationship, you need to do the opposite mapping by making a `MemberMappingOverride` class and there you mark inverse.

Hope this helps.